# How to align the input button of a form in the center?

Tags: html, css, input, sass, display

I want to center align the `input` of a form.

However, it is a project where there are multiple scss files and I don't want to break it.

I need to try to align it only by modifying the CSS that I show you here, so that it does not affect other elements of the form screen.
The form will not look very good since we use scss and there are variables not included in the code.

Now the `input` is left aligned.

I have tried the following code:

```css
display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between; 
align-items: center;
```

However it doesn't work, the input button is still aligned to the left.

Maybe the example I show is little

```css
.formulario {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.campo {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    label {
        flex: 0 0 10rem;
    }
    input {
        flex: 1;
        border: none;
        padding: calc(v.$separacion / 4);
        border-radius: 1rem;

        &:disabled {
            background-color: lighten(v.$negro, 30%);
            color: v.$blanco;
            cursor: not-allowed;
        }
    }
}

.boton {
    @include m.boton(v.$azul, v.$blanco);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.boton-eliminar {
    @include m.boton(v.$rojo, v.$blanco);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="nombre-pagina">LOGIN</h1>
<p class="descripcion-pagina">Inicia sesion con tus datos</p>

<form class="formulario" method="POST" action="/">
  <div class="campo">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input 
      type="email"
      id="email"
      placeholder="Tu Email"
      name="email"
    >
  </div>

  <div class="campo">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input 
            type="password"
            id="password"
            placeholder="Tu Password"
            name="password"
        />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="boton" value="Iniciar Sesión">

</form>



<div class="acciones">
    <a href="/crear-cuenta">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? Crear una</a>
    <a href="/olvide">¿Olvidaste tu password?</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your title and question don't really match. SCSS is processed into CSS, so by modifying SCSS, you are modifying CSS. When you ask how to align a form element without modifying the CSS... It's just not possible, and it doesn't seem to be what you're asking anyway. Please [edit] the title or the question so that they are consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @HereticMonkey . I use the translator and I didn't do it well.
I mean I'm using more scss files and I don't want to break it, now I'll try to edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<style>
.boton {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

This will align the submit button to the center. The display: block; property makes the element behave like a block-level element, and the margin: auto; property automatically adjusts the left and right margins and aligns the element horizontally in the center.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bring your all input in center then you have to simply give the css to your form **text-align:center;**

```
.formulario{
  text-align:center; 
}
```

And if you want to only align center your submit button then give it to **margin:auto**

```
.boton{
    margin:auto;
  }
```

Hope so your code will execute properly

Comment: Thanks @ChandramolPandey. `text-align:center;` doesn't work, but `margin:auto;` yes it works. I have already accepted the previous answer